# How to Get Data from CSV File and Send them to Excel Using Pentaho?

Tags: csv, mapping, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have a tabular csv file that has seven columns and containing the following data:

```
ID,Gender,PatientPrefix,PatientFirstName,PatientLastName,PatientSuffix,PatientPrefName
2 ,M     ,Mr           ,Lawrence        ,Harry          ,             ,Larry
```

I am new to pentaho and I want to design a transformation that moves the data (values of the 7 columns) to an empty excel sheet.  The excel sheet has different column names, but should carry the same data, as shown:

```
prefix_name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,maiden_name,suffix_name,Gender,ID
```

I tried to design a transformation using the following series of steps, but it gives me errors at the end that I could not interpret them.

[image: step]

What is the proper design to move the data from the csv file to the excel sheet in this case?  Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: If all you need to do is change column names, you can use the `Select values` step for that. If the problem is something else, please update the question with Excel output step configuration and error output.

Answer (score 2):

As @Brian.D.Myers mentioned in the comment you can use `select values` step. But here is how you do it step by step explanation.

[image: csv_to_excel_full_ktr]

1. Select all the fields from `CSV file input` step.
2. Configure the `select values` step as follows.

[image: select_values_configuration]

3. In the `Content` tab of `Excel writer` step click on Get fields button and fill the fields. Alternatively you can use `Excel output` step as well.